# ORACLE SQL Developer required property hostname cannot be null or empty

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, oracle12c

I installed the Oracle 12c2 client and fired up SQL developer for the first time.

The version is:
[image]

I then tried to add a connection I use but got an error message I don't understand:
[image]

I can't see a 'hostname' property anywhere.  What is the problem here?

Note that the connection works with sqlplus:
[image]

Comment: no that's the user name.  USRRBAT is the hostname on the SQL Plus command line.

Comment: I put it in the connection name.  Is that not correct?

Comment: yes there is! I have USRRBAT in the Connection Name field

Comment: Wait a minute, I think I see it.  The error message says "hostname" but what it really means is "Connect Identifier".  A tad confusing, but I got it to work.

Comment: Just a FYI, the most current copy of SQLDev can always be found here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html. What comes DIST with the DB quickly becomes out-of-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We pull the HOSTNAME, as well as the Port and Service/SID from the TNS entry you have specified.

And you have NOT specified a TNS entry.

So go find the one you have for 'usrrbat' and select it.

Or, SKIP all of that and manually supply the information in a 'Basic' connection type. Either way, we're using JDBC to connect to your database.

Having a TNSNames.ora file just makes getting there easier for you.

'Connection Name' is only used for 1 thing - labeling connections in the User Interface. It has ZERO to do with how a connection happens.

[image]

Comment: I have a TNSNames.ora file but no entry for USRRBAT.  Turns out it's resolved using LDAP.

Comment: @user1443098 glad you figured it out - either way, you need to supply the what/where info. I'll assume you saw the LDAP connection type and used that successfully.

Comment: nope. just used basic.  FWIW I'm not sure what our LDAP servers are.  They get found by magic